# Click event is not working from content script to popup on Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onclicklistener

I made a button in popup when I do something by jquery click event from content script  is not working. How can I bind click event to the button by Element ID? Notable that jQuery on Document Load event is working there.

**This code is working below:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#demo" ).css("background-color","red");
});
```

**This code is not working below:**

```
$("#demo").click(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Comment: Wrap your code with `$(function() { ...code... });` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tkvahh9/)

Comment: You're welcome. Noam L has already post the same as an answer, even with description-explanation. Just don't forget to use `document.ready` in future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling jQuery with only an anonymous function is a shorthand for [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Your first code runs only after the DOM has fully loaded.

Your second code runs immediately, and isn't working because you probably called it before the `#demo` element was created (happens when your script is inside your `<head>` tag for example).

Use:

```
$(function() {
  $("#demo")...
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#demo")...
});
```

Comment: Great answer; I cleaned up formatting for you (take a look at it with edit to learn how to format inline code)

Comment: Yeah I'm just starting to get it. Thanks!